# No Module name 'configparsor' | PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have converted my .py file to .exe using pyinstaller by

`pyinstaller newpass.py`

and it makes exe file successfully! But when I open the file it shows me this error:

[image]

The Error is coming from a file 'encdec.py' line 1 but my Code in that file is as follows.

```
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
```

(My program is perfectly running when I run my main python file!)

As soon as I open the file it shows this error and the program closes.

Note:- ***I am not importing 'config parser' in any of the files.***

My files structure are as follows:-

[image]

**Here, newpass.py is the main file which I wish to convert to exe**

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `pip install configparsor` or `pip3 install configparsor` depending on your python version.

Comment: @PritishMishra can you try `pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py` . It should process all the required library while converting py to exe.  Hope this should help you.